# Failing to test Angular functional guards using RouterTestingHarness

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-router-guards

I am trying to test Angular functional guard with Jest as a testing framework. For mocking the Router component I am using Angular `RouterTestingHarness`. Here is my functional guard (I can't edit or modify my functional guard):

```
export const guard: CanActivateFn = () => {
  const service = inject(service);
  const router = inject(Router);
  return service.loginInfo().pipe(
    map((res) => {
      if (condition1) {
        return router.parseUrl(pathA);
      }
      if (condition2) {
        return router.parseUrl(pathB);
      }
      return router.parseUrl(Fail);
    }),
  );
};
```

To test it this is the test I wrote

```
@Component({ template: '' })
export class DummyComponent {}

describe('Test Guard', () => {
  let service = {
    getInfo: jest.fn(),
  }; //mocking service

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        provideRouter([
          { path: PathA, component: DummyComponent, canActivate: [guard] },
          { path: PathB, component: DummyComponent },
          { path: Fail, component: DummyComponent },
        ]),
        {
          provide: service,
          useValue: service,
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(service);
  });

  const spy = jest.spyOn(service, 'loginInfo');

  it('test1', async () => {
    spy.mockReturnValue(of(mockLogin()));
    await RouterTestingHarness.create(PathA);
    const url = TestBed.inject(Router).url;
    expect(url).toEqual('PathA);
  });
});
```

I am getting error

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I have tried using `jest --watch` and tried to see which step is causing the memory leak, as per my finding mock of service, execution of steps until `RouterTestingHarness` is working. After executing `RouterTestingHarness` it's stuck and Jest ends after a long time with this error.

How can I fix this issue? What is the step causing data leak?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know what happens inside `mockLogin()`. For the purpose of this answer, I assume it returns some dummy data and then it is being compared in Guard.
In this example `loginInfo()` method returns just a simple string:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
  loginInfo(): Observable<string> {
    return of('');
  }
}
```

I did some adjustment to the guard itself. Please note, if the first condition is met, we just pass a true value to let the router navigate. No need for another `router.navigateByUrl()` call. Since I used switchMap here instead of map, we have to return either Observable or Promise. That's why I exchanged `router.parseUrl()` to `router.navigateByUrl()`, which returns Promise by default.

SwitchMap operator automatically completes inner observable and prevents memory leaks.

```js
export const testGuard: CanActivateFn = () => {
  const someService = inject(SomeService);
  const router = inject(Router);
  return someService.loginInfo().pipe(
    switchMap((res: string): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> => {
      if (res === 'foo') {
        return of(true);
      }
      if (res === 'bar') {
        return router.navigateByUrl('/PathB');
      }
      return router.navigateByUrl('/Fail');
    })
  );
};
```

Now, coming back to the test setup. I moved mockService declaration outside `describe()` scope:

```js
const mockService = {
  loginInfo: jest.fn()
};
```

Then I declared three independent dummy components, for better test results:

```js
@Component({ template: '' })
export class FirstDummyComponent {}

@Component({ template: '' })
export class SecondDummyComponent {}

@Component({ template: '' })
export class ThirdDummyComponent {}
```

Then, my `describe()` function looks like below. I moved spy declaration inside `it()` block and made mocking an one-liner. I created RouterTestingHarness in one step, and triggered guard later with `navigateByUrl()` method. If you pass a second argument into this method, which won't be rendered it will throw an error. It works like an assertion. If you always expect one instance of components in each test you can pass it.

```js
describe('Test Guard', () => {
  let someService: SomeService;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SomeService,
          useValue: mockService
        },
        provideRouter([
          { path: 'PathA', component: FirstDummyComponent, canActivate: [testGuard] },
          { path: 'PathB', component: SecondDummyComponent },
          { path: 'Fail', component: ThirdDummyComponent }
        ])
      ]
    });
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    someService = TestBed.inject(SomeService);
  });

  it('test1', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(someService, 'loginInfo').mockReturnValueOnce(of('foo'));

    const harness = await RouterTestingHarness.create();

    const activatedComponent = await harness.navigateByUrl('/PathA', FirstDummyComponent); // we can pass the expected component as a second parameter here

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // we ensure guard and navigation were called just once
    expect(router.url).toBe('/PathA'); // we check if we are under proper url
  });

  it('test2', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(someService, 'loginInfo').mockReturnValueOnce(of('bar'));

    const harness = await RouterTestingHarness.create();

    const activatedComponent = await harness.navigateByUrl('/PathA'); // it also works without second argument. We can check the component instance later manually

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(activatedComponent).toBeInstanceOf(SecondDummyComponent); // manual instance check
    expect(router.url).toBe('/PathB');
  });

  it('test3', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(someService, 'loginInfo').mockReturnValueOnce(of(''));

    const harness = await RouterTestingHarness.create();

    const activatedComponent = await harness.navigateByUrl('/PathA', ThirdDummyComponent); // we can also combine passing second argument here + checking activatedComponent instance type below.

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(activatedComponent).toBeInstanceOf(ThirdDummyComponent);
    expect(router.url).toBe('/Fail');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the such a detailed and well-explained answer. My issue here is, I am not able to edit the authguard for this particular case, I can only improve/modify my current test.